# ThingsBoard. Rule chains. Repeated REST API Call in one session

Tags: thingsboard

successful authorization with the use of REST API Call Node returns the session identifier and the key to the cookies. How can I make the next control call using REST API Call Node while saving the session?

Answer (score 1):

TbRestApiCallNode does not persist state. All headers and response body are added into message metadata and cannot be reused by default.

But it is also possible to workaround this:
Next node, after rest call, should save headers/body from metadata into attributes of a specific asset (for example Asset "Rest Service Session").
In this case, your chain will look like this:

1. read session info from asset
2. if session found - use it to make a rest call
3. if not found - authorize and save session in asset